# custom web server debuggin on visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I'm having issues debugging my ASP.Net web application. I am trying to debug it through our local network. I picked "Use custom web server" under the properties --> web section and I set the specific page to the path to the page that I'd like to see on that server. However, I keep getting "IIS does not list a web site that matches the launched URL" all the time. Everyone else on the network have no trouble debugging with exactly the same configuration.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Are you able to pull up that url in your browser? What is the URL?

Comment: yes the url works. I set the custom web server to "http://ourserver.ourcompany.ca:81" and the specific page is "/ApplicationName/SpecificApplication/DesktopDefault.aspx". If I combine the two I see the application in my web browser.

Comment: You might want to check out the solution posted here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1585732.aspx and also here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/310160/unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server if you provide us with more information such as your computer environment and the server environment then I might be able to provide you with some more help.

Comment: sure I'm running windows 7, visual studio 2010. The server is windows 2003 and IIS 6. Please let me know what other information would be helpful.

Comment: Additionally I should mention that some of the links recommend enabling "Windows authentication". I have that enabled. Also another link recommended installing IIS 6 Management Compatibility. I installed that on my local computer as well.

Comment: I've discovered a little more about my issue. Turns out that visual studio 2008 debugging works fine. The issue is only with 2010

Comment: Did you try running visual studio as administrator?

Comment: Hi DeviantSeev, thanks for all your help. I did try running it as administrator but it still didn't help. However, I managed to debug it in the end by doing "attach to process". I followed this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/IISRemoteDebugging.aspx I guess it will do for now.

Comment: I'm glad that you were able to get around the problem. If you ever find a solution, please come back and post a reply. It would be great to know what the fix was :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. To get it to debug finally I went to IIS Manager. Navigated to my site and selected .Net compilation. There I had to switch the behaviour to debug and it all started working.

Answer (score 1):

Just for others who find this page, I thought I'd add what worked for me.  In my case, it was none of the above.  I'd just forgotten to **run Visual Studio as Administrator**.